# R Reshape - Sum and Combine

Tags: r, sum, reshape

I am sure this is really simple but I can not get it to work

I need to sum two values while the other columns remain constant using reshape/melt:

Data Looks like this:

```
   ID         Value
1 2850508     1010.58828
2 2850508     94.37286
```

Desired Output:

```
   ID         Variable  Value
1 2850508     Cost     1104.96114
```

Current Output:

```
   ID         Variable  Value
1 2850508     Cost     1010.58828
2 2850508     Cost      94.37286
```

Current Code:

```
Sum <- melt(Data, id="ID", measured="Cost")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use the `aggregate` function.

```
aggregate(formula = . ~ ID, 
          data = Data , 
          FUN = sum)
##        ID    Value
## 1 2850508 1104.961
```

And to get your desired output, you have to `cbind` and rearrange:

```
cbind(aggregate(formula = . ~ ID, 
                data = Data , 
                FUN = sum), 
      Variable = "Cost")[, c("ID", "Variable", "Value")]
```

Comment: Perfect...its nice and fast too!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`: (I added two more IDs so there'd be more data):

`d` is your data

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Value=sum(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Variable="Cost") %>%
  select(ID,Variable,Value)



      ID Variable    Value
1 2850508     Cost 1104.961
2 2850509     Cost 1164.961
3 2850510     Cost 1047.961
```

Comment: package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)

Comment: Are you not able to update to a new version of `R`? I would highly recommend doing so, if you are able.

Comment: Work Computer...I will ask nicely!

Comment: Get those administrator rights. New versions of `R`, `RStudio`, etc. Always good to be able to update as needed. But definitely get the newest version of `R` if yours doesn't support `dplyr` (along with who knows how many other great packages). `R` is currently on `3.1.2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew and will get upgraded ASAP

Answer (score 1):

It is also very simple with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Variable = "Cost", Value = sum(Value)) , ID]
#         ID Variable    Value
# 1: 2850508     Cost 1104.961
```